# Configuration Setting

Tags: c#, app-config

This setting is not allowed in App.Config due to the error 
The element app settings has invalid element 'BscSerialNumber'. List of possible elements expected 'add,remove,clear'

```
  <add key="PreValue" value="<BscSerialNumber>"/>
```

The value `<BscSerialNumber>` is an actual string that i want in my setting.

Comment: Replace with special sequence like here. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607920/the-character-breaks-passwords-that-are-stored-in-the-web-config) See Kelsey's answer.

Comment: [A pretty good list can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091953/2099119)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the angle-brackets. Use `&lt;` instead of `<` and `&gt;` instead of `>`.

The appsetting entry should end up looking like this:

```
<add key="PreValue" value="&lt;BscSerialNumber&gt;"/>
```

When you read the setting in code, it will contain the string, including the angle-brackets:

[image]

Comment: Or as well get rid of them. I assume whatever value goes there, will always have the form "<SomeTagName>" ... So it can be surrounded by "<>" at the client's side with less headaches.

Comment: @Fildor We don't know if OP can make changes to the client that reads the values - but it definitely doesn't hurt to know how to escape characters in XML.

Comment: I agree. It's just another option.