# React Application works in browser but doesn't work in Cefsharp. Probably "Provisional headers are shown" issue

Tags: c#, wpf, reactjs, cefsharp

I host angular component what works as a map.
There is a search feature that is a text box that returns the list of strings:

[image]

It works fine when it runs on browser, but it doesn't when I run it in cef browser component.

There are request-response sequence from browser application that works fine:
[image]
There are request-response sequence from WPF Cef applications:
[image]

I believe that some configuration is missing for Cefsharp implementation. I tried all of things like "disable cache" etc., but it was all to no avail.

Additionally, for browser application that works, Security section shows "This page is not secure.":
[image]

Whereas for Cef application it is 'The security of this page is unknown.":

[image]

My react application runs from localhost, whereas application in cefsharp runs from embedded resource:

```
http://app//resource/BrowserEx.ViewModels/web-gis-app/build/common-components/cc-gis-viewer/index.html?
```

[image]
When I run the html file directly on browser on double click it throws exception:
[image]

I will appreciate any advice, suggestion or even hint.

Comment: Is that application available online or you run it from local html file?

Comment: In my cefsharp application it runs from embedded resource html file. Sorry, I forgot to mention this important information.

Comment: If from localhost you mean you run it from local IIS - what happens if you just open html file in browser (by just clicking on it, so running from local folder)?

Comment: No, I run it locally by node.js. But yes, once I run it through my Chrome browser - it is OK, but when I run by Cefsharp app - it cannot receive data.
When I run this html file directly on browser on double click it throws exception. I'm updating the question.

Comment: Well there is some cross-origin issue, but it's hard to debug it like that with screenshots, without actual source

Comment: Uploading to whole code is too much, but I can definitely can publish code segments that you think are important.

Comment: Well only minimal reproducable example is needed (so minimal code which reproduces your problem exactly).

Comment: I found the reason. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the reason by analyzing of my request-response URLs by *Fiddler*.
My URL in Cefsharp was incorrect.
Once I held my URLs in App.config file and config file doesn't like "&":
[image]

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607920/the-character-breaks-passwords-that-are-stored-in-the-web-config) I found the solution for the issue.

The solution was just to remove all *amp;* characters:
[image]
**Hence, conclusion of all this mishmash: don't use  `&amp;` while building your URL, - use `&` instead!**