# C# SQL Server Connection String contains html tag in the Password string-Error Web.config" is invalid with '<'

Tags: sql-server, character, connection-string

I recently got a SQL Server account which password containing the invalid html tags which web.config file could not pass the compile.

```
 <connectionStrings>  
    <add name="DBString" connectionString="Data Source=[server_name];Initial Catalog=[database_name];User ID=[username];Password=**4jghJ59<96>d6h6gghg!00**" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

The error: Application Configuration file "Web.config" is invalid. '<', hexadecimal value 0x3C...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The "&" character breaks passwords that are stored in the web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607920/the-character-breaks-passwords-that-are-stored-in-the-web-config)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the error, use two functions to encrypt and decrypt the password string.

Step 1: use EncodeTo64 to get the another string for the real password which will not include any special characters, put this string into your web.config file (Password="")
you could just put temp line of code to get the encryped string, copy/paste to your web.config file.

Step 2: use DecodeFrom64 to get the real password when connecting to the database in code.

```
public static string EncodeTo64(string toEncode)
{
        var toEncodeAsBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toEncode);
        var returnValue = System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);
        return returnValue;
}

public static string DecodeFrom64(string encodedData)
{
        var encodedDataAsBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);
        var returnValue = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(encodedDataAsBytes);
        return returnValue;
}
```