# Oracle: How to allow leading/trailing spaces in ODP.Net connection string values?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odp.net

My C# app connects to Oracle using following connection string format:

```
Data Source=tnsEntry;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Now if there's a user id that starts with space like `' abc'` (excluding quotes), how can I specify it in the connection string? Putting it in single/double quotes results in error Ora-1017: Invalid username/password.

Using Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.3.0. Connecting to Oracle 11g.

Reproducible at my end in this **minimal sample:**

```
using System;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var con = new OracleConnection("User Id=\" abc\";Password=system05;Data Source=REFUPG141");
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("connected.");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't think it s possible to create a user with leading/trailing  white space so why not just trim them ?

Comment: @haki it is possible.

Comment: Can't you use `@` before the connection String in the C# code? Look at the solution here also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824351/how-to-include-ampersand-in-connection-string-password-when-using-entity-framewo

Answer (score 0):

Surrounding the username with **double-quotes** worked for me:

Note that you need to use double-quotes when creating your user:

```
SQL> create user "  DUMMY" identified by "pass";

User created.

SQL> grant connect, create session to "  DUMMY";

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn "  DUMMY"/"pass";
Connected.
```

Then in .NET I've used this connection string and worked fine:

```
Data Source=localhost/mySid;User Id="  DUMMY";Password=pass
```

**[EDIT] Important information:**

I'm using the [Managed .NET Oracle Provider](http://www.nuget.org/packages/odp.net.managed/)

Comment: I tried this today with Managed .NET Oracle Provider that you mentioned. Still didn't work to my surprise. Could this be specific to my particular Oracles server instance?

Comment: That's odd. Yes, could be your Oracle version maybe. Here I'm running Oracle 11g.

Comment: @Karan: Also, could you please post the code (connection part) you are running this issue?

Comment: Oracle 11g here too. Also, I added the code in original post now.