# Apostrophe (single quote) in connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

I'm having a trouble with the `'` character in a connection string. Entity Framework throws an exception saying:

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index

I tried the answers suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824351/how-to-include-ampersand-in-connection-string-password-when-using-entity-framewo) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177861/escape-quote-in-web-config-connection-string) to no avail.

I also tried constructing it with `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class and got the same exception as a result.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

The connectionstring is indeed in the web.config file and it looks like this:

```
<add name="TestEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DAL.TestModel.csdl|res://*/DAL.TestModel.ssdl|res://*/DAL.TestModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\testsource;initial catalog=testdb;User Id=testuser;Password=test'password;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

the problem is with the `Password=test'password` bit.

1. I can't put it in double quotes because it's already surrounded by them.
2. I can't put it between `&quot;`-s because it's already surrounded by them too.
3. And I can't put it in single quotes because the single quote itself is what I'm trying to escape.

`Password='test&apos;password'` doesn't work.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question, the answers suggested in the other one aren't sufficient.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have finally stumbled upon a correct answer. It appears, you have to surround the value with single quotes and additionally duplicate the inner apostrophe in order to escape it, like this:

`Password='test''password'`

This is such a dumb problem to waste this much time on. I hope it saves somebody time in the future.

Thanks to everyone for participating.

Comment: Saved me a headache.

Comment: Your solution has helped me out. Thanks a ton. and for future readers: It's also worth checking if the password has also saved correctly in case you're only checking at the reading part.

Comment: Thanks a ton Man .. I was getting Mad in SSIS due to this issue.
Need to add a single quote at the start and end, also add a quote for each quote in between the password

Answer (score 3):

Assuming it is the password which contains a single quote, you should try enclosing the password in xml encoded double-quotes, something like this :

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.;
    Initial Catalog=MYDB; User ID=MyUser;Password=&quot;my'password&quot;;
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient";/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Assuming you are not in Xml context (as mentionned by @PanagiotisKanavos ) the ConnectionString initialization would look like :

```
var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;
    Initial Catalog=MYDB; User ID=MyUser;Password=\"my'password\";
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient")
```

Comment: The problem isn't about quotation in XML strings. In order to contain special characters, a property value must be enclosed in single or double quotation marks itself