# Scaffold dbContext in .net: Erro with password that cotains simple quote in the end

Tags: .net, scaffold, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I have a problem with connection string password to connect to database in visual studio.

In the end of password has a simple quote. I tried to escape using ' and others way like `password="****'", password='****'', password='****&apos;', password="****&apos;"`. I'm using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql. Can some one help me?

I tried this in visual studio PM console :

PM> Scaffold-DbContext "server=remoteServe, port=3306; User Id=Myuser; database=database; Password=1234'" Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql -OutputDir Models -ContextDir Context

return this erro:

```
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 108
```

Comment: Paste the actual command you are using (replace server, user and password with fake ones) and specify, what kind of shell (cmd, powershell, bash, etc.) you are using.

Comment: What is the actual error text you are getting? BTW, you have typo in 'passsword' word itself.
Also please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/36479541/822455

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your password is `1234'`, the following command will work:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "server=127.0.0.1;user=test;password='1234''';database=test" [...]
```

Use a pair of single quotes around the password value and escape all single quotes of the password value with a second single quote.