# Guidewire postgresql database connection

Tags: database, postgresql, guidewire

I have a bunch of errors trying to connect GW to PostgreSQL. I have tried a lot of changes in database-config.xml
On of them is:

```
  <database
autoupgrade="full"
name="BillingCenterDatabase"
dbtype="postgresql">
<dbcp-connection-pool
  jdbc-url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test?user=postgres&password=qwerty;"/>
```

It gives me fewer errors, but I still can't connect.

```
[Fatal Error] :25:72: The reference to entity "password" must end with the ';' delimiter.
```

It pretends I have to to put a semicolon in place of

```
password;=qwerty
```

If I put it here, I've got an error: The entity "password" was referenced but not declared.
The GW suggestion for the psql is:

```
Expected: jdbc:postgresql://<host>[:<port>]/<dbname>?user=<user>&password=<password>
```

Maybe some experienced folks may help me with it?

Comment: The ampersand `&` in the connection string probably has to be escaped as `&amp;`. Similar discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3824422/18667225

Comment: @Markus thank you, Sir. Works for me. How can I apply your answer as a solution?

Comment: I have added an answer that you can upvote and/or accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ampersand `&` in the connection string has to be expressed by the built-in entity `&amp;` like this:

```
jdbc-url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test?user=postgres&amp;password=qwerty;"
```

Otherwise the `XML`-parser will try to interpret the following word (here `password`) as entity which would have to be terminated by `;`. This explains the misleading error message.

Similar discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3824422/18667225